# Spring JPA One To Many Infinite Recursion

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jackson

im trying to return to a JPA data (converted to DTO, ofcourse) where it has a `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` bidirectional relationship. Im currently apply thing [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue). The problem is that the output is recusrive. comments has post has comments then has posts (comments -> post -> coments -> so on..).

I only wnat to have something like this

```
{
    "post_id": 1
    "user": {
        // user data
    },
    "description": "some description",
    "images": "{images,images}",
    "tags": "{tags, tags}",
    "comments": [
     {
        //some comments data

     },
     {
        //some comments data
     }
    ]
    "lastUpdated": "2020-04-08T14:23:18.000+00:00"
}
```

Here are my code

**This is my Posts.class**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Posts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long post_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Users user;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="images")
    private String images;

    @Column(name="tags")
    private String tags;

    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "comments" ,"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" }, allowSetters = true)
    //@JsonManagedReference
    private List<Comments> comments;


    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private Date lastUpdated;


    public void addComments(Comments comment) {
        this.comments.add(comment);
    }
}
```

**Here is my PostDTO.class**

```
@Data
public class PostDTO {

    private Long post_id;
    private UserDTO user;
    private String description;
    private String images;
    private String tags;
    private List<CommentsDTO> comments;
    private Date lastUpdated;


}
```

**This is my Comments.class**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Comments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="comment_id")
    private Long comment_id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Users user;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="images")
    private String images;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="post_id" , nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "post" ,"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" }, allowSetters = true)
    //@JsonBackReference
    private Posts post;

    @Column(name="last_updated")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastUpdated;

}
```

**Here is my CommentsDTO.class**

```
@Data
public class CommentsDTO {

    private Long comment_id;

    private UserDTO user;

    private String description;

    private PostDTO post;

    private String images;

    private Date lastUpdated;
}
```

**Here is my REST Controller**

```
@GetMapping
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<PostDTO>>  getAll() throws Exception {

    return new ResponseEntity<List<PostDTO>>(service.getAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Here is my service**

```
public List<PostDTO> getAll() throws Exception  {
    return repo.findAll()
               .stream()
               .map(this::convert)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private PostDTO convert(Posts e) {
    return  mapper.map(e, PostDTO.class);
}
```

Hope someone can shed light on my issue. Kinda lost as of this time.

Comment: Do you required data upto n level ?

Comment: sorry, i updated the post with my expected output

Comment: Can you try `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "post" ,"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" }, allowSetters = true)
private List<Comments> comments;`For post also change the same and try

Comment: its the same :(

Comment: Can you update in the code what you have done ?

Comment: okay, updated it

Comment: Can you add your PostDTO class

Comment: @AbinashGhosh added the DTO

Comment: please add commentDTO also

Comment: Thats help me to find out the problem

Comment: Added CommentDTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is when you convert `Post` into `PostDTO` then by using ModelMapper it calls all field's getter of Post for `PostDTO`. So this happened recursively for this 
`mapper.map(e, PostDTO.class)`

So, just remove `private PostDTO post` from CommentDTO ,
then modelmapper don't try to set PostDTO->comment-> post field.
And you don't need bidirectional relation in DTO. DTO is all about what you want to show in response.

Comment: ahh i see, it worked, but how do i apply this to the actual entity since i cannot just remove the other due to the `OneToMany` relationship?

Comment: you are removing from DTO not from entity so your relationship remains

Comment: Yes, i know, i was just curios how do you do the same with entity without removing the post field on `Comments` entitiy. Because when i try to return `Posts` entity on `ResponseEntity` the same recusion issue occurs.

Comment: Why you need this with entity because you are going to call post getter for comments entity, JPA fetch data when you call the gettter for lazy

Comment: When you try to return Posts entity on ResponseEntity that recursion happened becasuse of deserialization call  all getter of Posts. Thats why it is a good practice to use DTO for response

Comment: I see, so the constraint when using Entity is that due to the annotated relationship between entities it will cause deserialization issue, that is to control the constraint another level is introduced that is the DTOs

Comment: Yes, by using DTO you show what you want to in response. Recursively fetch is feature not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the json serialization cycle on the wrong class.

You are sending a list of `PostDTO`, but applied `JsonBackReference` to `Comments` and `JsonManagedReference` to `Posts`

**Update**

Note that `ObjectMapper` class, `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` may from 2 packages

- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
- com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
- com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference

or:

- org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
- org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonManagedReference
- org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonBackReference

If you are not consistent between all of them, the mis-matched annotation will be ignored and you will still experience infinite loop during serialization.

Comment: I don't think PostDTO` has a problem because i tried directly sending `Posts` back. Both has the same issue. I think there is the problem with Back and Managed Reference which i am at a lost.

Comment: am using fasterxml for both

Comment: also, i have no `codehaus` dependencies in my dep tree

Comment: Have you tried to serialize manually: `String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(posts);` and check if that reproduces the issue?

Comment: yes, tried this part on my controller prior to return `ResponseEntity`and confirmed it via debug mode and surrounding it with `try-catch`, that line produces the same issue

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works perfectly on mine machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonIgnoreProperties along with Manage and backreference .

```
 @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "comments")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    public class Comments {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="comment_id")
        private Long comment_id;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        private Users user;

        @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;

        @Column(name="images")
        private String images;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name ="post_id" , nullable = false)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "comments" ,"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" }, allowSetters = true)
       @JsonBackReference
        private Posts post;

        @Column(name="last_updated")
        @LastModifiedDate
        private Date lastUpdated;

    }
```

And Your Post class should be

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Posts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long post_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Users user;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="images")
    private String images;

    @Column(name="tags")
    private String tags;

    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "post" ,"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" }, allowSetters = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Comments> comments;


    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private Date lastUpdated;


    public void addComments(Comments comment) {
        this.comments.add(comment);
    }
}
```

Also I would suggest to Use Getter and Setter annotation instead of @Data .Because Tostring() method will cause recursion also .